# Alignment issue in the Tags page - Legend tags section

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, per-site-meta

In the bottom of the [Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags), the Legend tags section is not aligned with the pagination section. The issue exists in all per-site-meta.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Legent Tags]

There is an issue in the `#tags-legend` CSS class. 
`#tags-legend { margin-bottom: 15px;` Changing the style to `margin-top: 15px;` it aligned properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment issue has been fixed recently.

The CSS class `#tags-legend` changed to `{ margin-top: 20px; }` and solved the issue.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Tags page - legend section]